# Is there any way to build a function from NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, selector

Lets say I download some text from webservice contain objective-c code, is there any way to make it selector?

**EDIT:**
I edited my title, what I mean is building a function from downloaded string at runtime.

Comment: So you want to download some code from internet and run it on device? Not possible if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: you have to set string as uilabel/uitextfield as a text set it and set tap gesture on it ,that's at.

Comment: A function and a selector are not remotely the same thing. A function is a sequence of executable code; a selector is just an identifier.

Comment: Thats what I meant, download additional source code and and compile in runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uhh, what do you mean obj-c code...

Are you downloading a class/code that you need to compile at runtime?

or you already have these methods in your implementation, the service only tells you what methods to call?

If the latter is correct, then you can use this:

`SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"methodName")`

beware that if this method contains parameters you will a string like this:

`SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"methodNameWithParam:anotherParam:")`

[NSSelectorFromString ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString)

If the former is correct, welcome to the [Objective-c runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html), It is technically possible but i **do not** know the apple guidelines will take too kindly to you downloading and patching code at runtime.

hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is compiling code in runtime, is there any sample to start with?

Comment: @IdanMoshe: I don't think you'll find many examples of compiling source at runtime. It's a really unusual requirement for Objective-C. Most programs that dynamically load code would load machine code, not source. The bird's eye view of the solution is, you'll have to bundle a compiler with your app.

Comment: @Chuck, its not as hard as you might think ;)
its not getting compiled in the usual sense, more linked/patched at runtime. The runtime has methods to add classes, and add methods & implementations. Check out:
[Mike Ash, adding classes at runtime](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html)
and the [Runtime reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html). **BUT these patched classes won't persist** they will exist only while the application is in memory.

Comment: @cream-corn: Yes, creating classes dynamically is not hard — but that is a totally different topic from executing arbitrary source code at runtime, which is what Idan is talking about.

Comment: Depending on what the overall motivation is; the code can be organised into objects, methods, But yes; you are correct in you cannot execute code from a string. Besides, apple **will not** approve any code that downloads additional code/libraries and links them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSSelectorFromString()` function to get a `SEL` (selector) from an `NSString` object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want load additional functionalitiy from webservices? 
Do you have just **functions/selectors** names in that text or **bodies/implementations** also?
In latter case you can't run non-compiled code, you should first compile it and then, dependent whether platform enables you to load binaries at the runtime - you can try to run it.

If it's just method names -

```
NSSelectorFromString()
```